# django socialregistration error help

Tags: django, facebook, registration

I was hoping to get some assistance using the django social registration app.

I am getting this error: TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/login/
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'facebook_login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

So far I have:  installed the dependencies; put socialregistation in my python/django working directory, added it to the installed apps and sync'd  the dbase; added the middleware;entered the facebook api id and secret key into settings; added 'django.core.context_processors.request' to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS; added the "urls url(r'^social/$', include('socialregistration.urls')),", and added the template code "{% load facebook_tags %} {% facebook_button %}{% facebook_js %}".

Now I have the standard login working on this already, but that should conflict since the url name is facebook_login.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: r'^social/$' <- '$' is not needed

Comment: removing the $ actually fixed the whole problem.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

most probably you do not have `FACEBOOK_API_KEY` set in your `settings.py`